# Python AssertionError

Tags: python, class, attributes

This is what I am trying to do with my below code.

> The class Apple should take 4 constructor inputs: the color (color), the name of the apple variety (variety_name), the size (size), and the place it grew in (place_grown), in that order. Those inputs should be assigned to the following instance variables: color, variety, size, grown_in.
>
> The class Apple should also have a string method, which should return
>   a string of the format
>
> ```
> A <SIZE> <COLOR> apple of the <VARIETY> variety, grown in <PLACE GROWN IN>.
> ```
>
> The `for_pies` method should return the boolean value True if the
>   variety is "Granny Smith", "Braeburn", or "Golden Delicious", and if
>   the variety value for that Apple instance is anything else, the method
>   should return the boolean value False.

Currently, I am receiving 2 errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Apple.py", line 312, in test_apple9
self.assertEqual(ap2.__str__(), "A large yellow apple of the Golden Delicious variety, grown in the United States.")
AssertionError: 'A large yellow apple of the Golden Delicious variety, grown in the United States ' != 'A large yellow apple of the Golden Delicious variety, grown in the United States.'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Apple.py", line 315, in test_apple10
self.assertEqual(ap2.__str__(),"A medium red apple of the Braeburn variety, grown in WA.")
AssertionError: 'A medium red apple of the Braeburn variety, grown in WA ' != 'A medium red apple of the Braeburn variety, grown in WA.'
```

Code:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, color, variety_name, size, place_grown):
        self.color = color
        self.variety = variety_name
        self.size = size
        self.place_grown = place_grown

    def __str__(self):
        return "A %s %s apple of the %s variety, grown in %s ." % (
            self.size, self.color, self.variety, self.place_grown)

    def for_pies(self):
        return self.variety in ("Granny Smith", "Braeburn", "Golden Delicious")

    ap2 = Apple("green","Granny Smith","large","Sydney, Australia")
    print ap2 # Should print: A large green apple of the Granny Smith variety, grown in Sydney, Australia
    print ap2.for_pies() # should print True

    ap3 = Apple("red","Mystery variety", "small","Michigan")
    print ap3.for_pies() # should print False
    print ap3 # should print: A small red apple of the Mystery variety variety, grown in Michigan
```

---

Different value tests:

```
import unittest

class Problem4(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_apple10(self):
        ap2 = Apple("red","Braeburn","medium","WA")
        self.assertEqual(ap2.__str__(),"A medium red apple of the Braeburn variety, grown in WA.")
    def test_apple9(self):
        ap2 = Apple("yellow","Golden Delicious","large","the United States")
        self.assertEqual(ap2.__str__(), "A large yellow apple of the Golden Delicious variety, grown in the United States.")
```

Comment: `!=` is a comparison operator, not an assignment. Use `=` instead. I'm not sure why you are using tuples of possible values, your assignment doesn't ask you to validate the values.

Comment: @  Martijn Pieters great I took away the !=, now I am receiving the  error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Apple.py", line 136, in <module>
    print ap2 # Should print: A large green apple of the Granny Smith variety, grown in Sydney, Australia
  File "Apple.py", line 123, in __str__
    %(self.size,self.color,self.variety_name,self.place_grown)
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with `AssertionErrors`?

Comment: @ martineau I changed the title, originally the problem started with a different error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not assigning anything in `__init__`. You appear to be making a series of comparisons (`!=` means *not equal to*) with some tuples; because `self.color` doesn't exist yet, that then leads to the exception you see.

Assignment is `=` (and you do use assignment in the `for_pies`, so you know how to use this):

```
def __init__(self, color, variety_name, size, place_grown):
    self.color = color
    self.variety = variety_name
    self.size = size
    self.place_grown = place_grown
```

Note that the *order* of the arguments also needed adjusting there, and that I corrected the name of the `variety` attribute to match your requirements.

Next, your `__str__` method will fail, because it uses several non-existing `%` formatters. Just use `%s` everywhere:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "A %s %s apple of the %s variety, grown in %s " % (
        self.size, self.color, self.variety, self.place_grown)
```

In other words, those are not the initial letters of the attribute names. I also added a comma between `variety` and `grown`.

Next, you can return the result of an `in` comparison directly, no need to use `if...else`:

```
def for_pies(self):
    return self.variety in ("Granny Smith", "Braeburn", "Golden Delicious")
```

Note that this method doesn't need to take `variety_name` as an argument! Your assignment tells you to use the `self.variety` instance attribute instead.

The completed class then is:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, color, variety_name, size, place_grown):
        self.color = color
        self.variety = variety_name
        self.size = size
        self.place_grown = place_grown

    def __str__(self):
        return "A %s %s apple of the %s variety, grown in %s " % (
            self.size, self.color, self.variety, self.place_grown)

    def for_pies(self):
        return self.variety in ("Granny Smith", "Braeburn", "Golden Delicious")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign attributes of instance. Here is right code:

```
class Apple():
    def __init__(self, color, variety_name, size, place_grown):
        self.color = color
        self.variety_name = variety_name
        self.size = size
        self.place_grown = place_grown
```

Change formatting:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "A %s %s apple of the %s variety grown in %s " \
            %(self.size,self.color,self.variety_name,self.place_grown)
```

Here change `self.variety` to `self.variety_name`:

```
def for_pies(self):
        return self.variety in ["Granny Smith", "Braeburn", "Golden Delicious"]
```

Then you can write following assignments:

```
ap2 = Apple("green","Granny Smith","large","Sydney, Australia")
print ap2 # Should print: A large green apple of the Granny Smith variety, grown in Sydney, Australia
print ap2.for_pies() # should print True

ap3 = Apple("red","Mystery variety", "small","Michigan")
print ap3.for_pies() # should print False
print ap3 # should print: A small red apple of the Mystery variety variety, grown in Michigan
```

Comment: `for_pies` needs no argument, by the way.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters and @ Oleksandr Pryhoda Great, that part works, but now I am getting the error TypeError: for_pies() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). Which isn't making sense to me.

Comment: @  Martijn Pieters My apologies I overlooked that. When I try to test the above ( edited code) it fails against 2 other test values. Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: @ Oleksandr Pryhoda  Sure I made an edit to my original question to cover the new AssertionError I am receiving.

Comment: You just add to your test sentences a point in the end. Remove it) Pay attention what your program return and what test are you writting

Comment: @Oleksandr Pryhoda I added a "." but it still is failing with the same assertion error.

Comment: @Oleksandr Pryhoda nevermind there was a space before the period that was messing it up. Thank you!